# How to get wordpress empty content list

Tags: wordpress

i make two list theme

1.the posts have featured image and title, but empty content. i want get this list.

2.and other posts with content list.

I don't have any idea, help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'order' => 'desc');

$blank_posts = array();

$posts = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $posts->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
       $content = get_the_content();
        if($content == '') { 
            array_push( $blank_posts, $post);
        }
    endwhile;
endif;

/* print all blank content posts */
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($blank_posts);

/* loop */

if(!empty($blank_posts)){
    foreach ($blank_posts as $pst) {
        echo "ID= ". $pst->ID . ', '. "Title= ". $pst->post_title .'<hr />';
    }
}
```

Comment: it dont work...Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => )

Comment: look like good, but how to use this? output Array ( [0] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 51 [post_author] => 1 this i Don't understand, sorry my bad

Comment: yes, thanks man,looks much better, buuut i want add some like featured image and comment list on this? so so so sorry, Teach me some
sample. thanks so much

Comment: get featured image by `$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($pst->ID),"full");
echo $image[0];` and see link to get comments list: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/115076/86151